# drupal 7 2nd and 3rd level of node reference

Tags: drupal, reference, entity

I have a view that shows the reference between node , but I would also display the reference of the first references and so on , is it possible to generate views and possibly a reference tree ? How can I achieve this?

Example: Node 1 reference Node 2 reference Node 3 reference Node 4
See also the image
[image: Reference and sub reference]

How to see the reference and sub reference like my example?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Every referencing (sql join) in views interface should be added as Relationship under Advanced options. When you are adding new Relationship pay attention that you select correct one - for every one there is a short explanation what content type and what field is it about (how that join will be made). After that, when you want to display some field value from some Relationship while adding that field make sure that you also select appropriate Relationship.

Also you can turn on "Show the SQL query" under view options, so you can see is SQL generated by views right or not.